# Rextester has officially been hacked. Where do we go from here?

Tags: discussion, support, external-links

The following screen capture says it all when visiting www.rextester.com:

[image]

A few days ago, I was blasted by someone on a Stack Overflow question for including a link to a Rextester demo. The user, who probably also downvoted me, mentioned something about Rextester being used to inject scripts in a malicious way.  I shrugged this off, having had only positive experiences with the site over the years. But now, I see that Rextester removed itself.

What should we all do about our old questions which now likely contain dead or at least unsafe testing links? I have added a Rextester demo for Java, SQL, and R questions many times (hundreds or more). Where do we go from here?

Comment: It is a public service message.  Posted by the site owner or a concerned user, probably the former.  You *might* worry about the users you sent there that used the site when it was hacked without that announcement.  But that problem is fixed and it is everybody's own responsibility to browse safely anyway.  If you fret about the DVs then you'd have to edit those posts.

Comment: Is the website going to be fixed and back up in the near future?

Comment: @Cœur You need to ask the site owner for that....

Comment: what makes you think rextester removed itself? that looks like typical defacement from a script kiddie not an official notice that the site is permanently closed.

Comment: @Cœur The site seems to be up at this moment.

Comment: SO could consider building their own, it'd be rather useful (I think). And of course there is a lot of alternative sites that can be used instead as well.

Comment: Looks like they were [hacked by a pirate](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/HackedByAPirate).

Comment: Is there any kind of announcement about the situation from the people who maintain the site? Can someone reach out to them to find out what's going on?

Comment: @MartinSmith - rextester removed itself much in the same way as my brother used to tell me to stop punching myself.

Comment: Blatant site hacks like this are not usually dangerous. The bad hacks are when everything still looks and works as it did beforehand.

Comment: @jpmc26 rextester is working now.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yes, but it's still known to be vulnerable, which is more what this post seemed to be about. The maintainer has openly admitted they haven't yet determined where the security hole is, much less fixed it. So it could be hacked again at any time, perhaps more maliciously than before. The public nature of this discussion may even make them a more attractive target for an attacker.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Which is what Yvette is suggesting. People don't like it much, for *some* reason.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Apparently the [site has been rebuilt](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/375624/1115360).

Answer (score 350):

I'm the maintainer of rextester. First of all, it has indeed been hacked. I'm looking into it.

It has happened before a few times usually someone breaking the backend. I see it as a fun process as I get to learn and then I patch the hole and the service gets more secure. Hackers probably see it as fun too and generally break stuff in a kind manner, this time too, it could be far worse. After all it is a site for them to use too.

The not so good news are that I could not determine how they did it yet. Someone was able to modify master page inserting some html into it (very bad I know). I've improved logging system and have some ideas to look at. But it might happen again. If the hacker reports how he did that it would be great help!

I know this sounds pretty amateurish, but well that's what it is. It is still fun project and I'm determined to patch this vulnerability. Sorry everyone, what else can I say...

**update**

So I've got new server and put web pages there without any user code running on the same server. Attack shouldn't happen again, if the server gets hacked it will be local to the language running there. Not sure if I want to open source the project as I imagine this will be hell lot of a work.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/182281).

Comment: @ren Have you considered open sourcing your code? That way the community could help you make the site safe, and quite likely give other improvements too.

Comment: @DavidG Open-sourcing leaks - yet probably unknown - vulnerabilities.

Comment: @LMD That's kind of the point; open-sourcing it would allow the community to identify vulnerabilities and submit patches for them.

Comment: @TylerH Yes, but you probably create more possible threats than vulnerabilities fixed.

Comment: @LMD I'd posit that you will fix more issues than you create. With such a small dev team of 1, it can be incredibly difficult to keep up with security issues. Can you show me any project that got hacked just because they opened up access?

Comment: @LMD If that were the case then open source software would not be so prevalent. Time has shown that the benefits far outweigh the risks in most cases.

Comment: @DavidG I think the concern is that when you first open source, everyone can find the vulerabilities _and immediately abuse them_. Even assuming the community helps you patch them long term, you've temporarily made yourself _really_ open to abuse.

Comment: @Mooing Yes I realise that, I'm saying that it's unlikely that will happen. The benefits vastly outweigh the problems.

Comment: @LMD Your concern is why I'd argue for a private review with some trusted individuals before open sourcing. Once they can get the system into a fairly hardened state, open sourcing to *maintain* that level of hardening makes the most sense. In the long run, the extra eyes will definitely pay off; it's the short term that would be concerning if it suddenly went open source.

Comment: @jpmc26: That would indeed be a generally reasonable approach. That said, given that the code currently contains at least one vulnerability that has demonstrably been exploited but has not yet been found by the maintainer, I'd say that *in this particular case* finding and patching that vulnerability ASAP would seem more important than worrying too much about the risk of *other* vulnerabilities being found and exploited.

Comment: @jpmc26 Alternatively, one could open-source module by module. First the login script, then the html generator, file upload, etc.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen There are at least two people who have a hope of finding the bug quickly: 1) the maintainer, and 2) the attacker. It's possible the vulnerability is worse than the hacker currently realizes, and we can't assume good faith, by definition.

Comment: You need to virtualize the runtime environment. And no, docker and jails don't provide sufficient level of containment.

Answer (score 16):

> What should we all do about our old questions which now likely contain dead or at least unsafe testing links? ... Where do we go from here?

Rextester is up and running again. It was defaced and the security hole is not fixed yet, according to the [owner](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/375624/1536976). I would therefore regard Rextester as not very reliable at least in the near future.

I recommend to consider using an available, alternative external service in the near future. Using an alternative service is not a guarantee of no malfunction either, but better than using a service that has known unfixed security holes.

That's why it's important that every question and answer stands on its own as much as possible. Would Rextester really been shut down for good, demos and such would have needed to be recreated solely from the content stored here.

Update: The owner of Rextester improved the security considerably (see the answer by ren). This means that Rextester is probably again as recommendable as any other service.

Comment: I have largely switched to dbfiddle.uk at this point, at least for SQL demos.  Better support for the latest databases.

Comment: yeh it's a good example of why the site asks for each post to be self contained. Even links to docs for large organisations like MS die, as software is updated.

Comment: There is not much point in using an "_alternative external service_" because the issue has **not been identified**: which means the issue may also impact alternative services. Or it could be an admin password leak, which would now be solved by changing it.

Comment: When there is an unsolved murder case, you don't ask all the neighborhood to move to a different town. So don't jump at using an "_alternative external service_" until there is a pattern or a known unsolved cause.

Comment: @Cœur "...because the issue has not been identified: which means the issue may also impact alternative services...." It's less likely though unless you assume that all services work the same way. I guess there is a certain probability that the problem is unique to Rextester, which means using alternative services you should be safer on average. " ...until there is a pattern or a known unsolved cause." This is a known unsolved case. The analogy with the murder in town is a bit off here, I think.

Comment: @Trilarion hum, let me try this one: "_if a self-driven car has one single accident, you don't immediately banish this car brand in favor of alternative brands._"

Comment: @Cœur Analogies have only a very limited use. I could find others saying the opposite. Arguments beyond what is already said are seldom to be found in analogies, I find. I mostly ignore them. I already understand that you disagree with my recommendation.

Comment: OK, then, without analogies: you "_recommend using an alternative service_" as it's "_better than using a service that has known unfixed security holes_". And I'd like to highlight that this is not enough of a reason to do so in the current circumstances, as it's possible that every website on the internet has unfixed security holes.

Comment: And some other factors are possible of bigger importance: 1. features of the platform, 2. popularity of the platform, 3. quality of service, 4. unknown security holes, 5. impact of changing all the links each time such event occurs, 6. probability that rextester was targeted because it was being popular, meaning that changing platform would just make the new platform the target of attacks, 7. probability that a competitor targeted rextester, which means we would be moving to the hands of the attacker.

Comment: @Cœur but the imidiate issue *has* been identified: someone was able to manipulate the html code of the site. My reading of the owner's post is that this happened on the server. According to the owner, this someone is at the moment most likely to be able to change files again. Of course every webservice/webserver has the potential to be vulnerable, but this one *is* vulnerable at the moment. While rextester may not be the biggest target or contain sensible user data, the hacker could still use it to deliver malicious js to the users or try to steal the login credentials

Comment: @cypherabe Hum, makes sense. But then I do not know what can possibly trigger the decision to ever come back to rextester.

Comment: @Cœur Either rextester finds out how it was hacked or no other hack occurs over a significant period of time.

Comment: @Cœur The only way it could regain my trust at this point is get the site (and server) hardened and then go open source. If, in the mean time, they lose significant user share that never comes back, that's on them for not doing a better job securing their site. If we do something like blacklist the URL, they'd need to start a Meta discussion about getting removed because they dealt with the issues.

Comment: "that's on them for not doing a better job securing the site", they probably don't have millions of dollars for that and even with that, 100% security will never exists.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 7):

I'd recommend editing out any links to the sites from posts with a link to this meta post with "the www.rextester.com site has been compromised" in the edit reason.

If this edit invalidates an answer as a result of the edit, custom flag for mod attention stating this, or use the Not An Answer flag.

I've also featured this post for the time being, so it's easy for people to see there's an issue with the site and what they should do about it.

I've pinged the community team for a mass edit.

Comment: I don't like the idea to flag as NAA just because a third party site got hacked

Comment: @SagarV It's not because a third party was hacked. If these edits (removing the links) make the answers useless, they were NAA to begin with.

Comment: @yivi I will add, as a comment, that I almost always treat demos as nice-to-have features in an answer.  For example, in a SQL answer I might give a demo, but in no way should the validity of that answer depend on the demo.  So, ideally, having SO remove these broken links should not affect too many answers (I hope).

Comment: I dont see it is necessary to mass edit thousands of posts because of a presumably transient issue. I dont see the message shown in the OP when visiting https://rextester.com

Comment: It seems like the site has been fixed in the meantime. No need to mass-edit IMHO.

Comment: [1/2] We should certainly be cautious using the site. There has not yet been a statement from the owner as far as I can find, either acknowledging the hack or telling us about a fix. Imo it would be best to treat the site as  compromised until it's confirmed that it's fixed. At any random time, malicious code could be inserted in the site, and the GitHub and discussion group are totally inactive, so I'm not confident the issue is fixed. If one were to exploit a hack, they would be wise to leave the site as intact as possible.

Comment: [2/2] Like Hans said, the _hacked_ message is a public service message. It's gone without follow-up, so we should thread _very_ carefully

Comment: Could you tell us how to easily bring up a list of our own questions and answers which contain a link to rextester? I know I've used it, but I can't remember when, and searching for "user:nnnnnnn rextester" doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @m69 `user:me url:rextester`

Comment: Editing pre-existing answers to abridge user-created content (the rextester link) seems precipitous to remedy something that might well be temporary.  Does Stack Exchange have an ability to replace direct links with "redirect notice" links (e.g. like the ones [here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/116854)) that could include security warnings?

Comment: By the way, to those seeking to view the rextester site, it looks like https:// works but http:// was giving me a 404. No reflection on its trustworthiness, just never tried the site before and pasting www.rextester.com into my address bar only gave me said 404. Aaand now it doesn't anymore. That might just be my browser being clever.

Comment: Is there precedent for immediately having the community team mass-edit to remove all links to a site based on a past security flaw? It seems like that has the potential to destroy a *lot* of content, and seems like a dramatic step for an individual mod to take without strong community consensus.

Comment: @SamHanley like mentioned by Tim Biegeleisen, this is a site for demoing answers, so it's not like actual *content* of the answers should be in danger of being destroyed. We do still expect answers to be self-contained, not depending on some external resource. That hasn't changed.

Comment: Oh come on, at this point I feel people are just downvoting because it's Yvette...  Yvette is right, and the person hasn't even fixed the security hole despite the site getting back online.   We shouldn't be using this site at all if such major security issues exist **and persist** after being hacked.

Comment: Ideally SO would be able to implement something where links to this site would, temporary, go somewhere else, like this meta post, or a similar one explaining what's going on and why their link isn't working, rather than to the site itself, and that the temporary redirect could be removed when SO has confidence in the site being stable.  Since I don't think such a feature exists, this is probably the best option in the short term.

Comment: Talk about scare mongering.

Comment: @opa people are downvoting not because its Yvette but because it's a stupid idea.

Comment: If removing a code demo invalidates an answer it should never had been considered an answer in the first place.

Comment: @opa In this case it's probably because the website is fixed (for a permanently hacked website, this would be the appropriate action). I have no evidence whether target downvote exists, either...

Comment: @user202729 Read the maintainers own post, he got it back up but doesn't know the vulnerability, [*it is still there, and sounds like it was a pretty giant deal*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/375624/2036035) with the potential to hurt end users.

Comment: @opa Probably because of [this comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/375602/rextester-has-officially-been-hacked-where-do-we-go-from-here/375603?noredirect=1#comment640118_375603) saying that the problem is "transient".

Comment: @user202729  I wasn't asking a question?  I'm confused on how what you just replied with was a response to what I said.

Comment: @opa That comment disagrees with the post. If people think the reason in the comment is valid, they downvote the post. In reality, the problem is not fixed (i.e., the comment is wrong).

Comment: @user202729  Ohhhh I thought you were coming from a completely different angle, what you said may be the case as well.

Comment: @opa: And this is why users have antivirus and other protection on their own devices. Even if the site got hacked by a malicious party, there's a lot a user can do to protect themselves. We don't need a mass-edit to remove a valid link because of a __temporary__ issue.